# How to query the Wordpress API by ACF properties?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to query the Worpress API based on ACF properties.

If I don't include a query, I get this output:

```
[{"id":215,"date":"2018-08-05T09:21:37","date_gmt":"2018-08-5T08:21:37","guid":{"rendered":"x"},"modified":"2018-08-05T09:21:37",
"modified_gmt":"2018-08-05T08:21:37","slug":"sasradisson","status":"publish","type":"hotel","link":"https:x",
"title":{"rendered":"SAS Radisson"},"template":"","acf":{"stad":{"value":"barcelona","label":"barcelona"},
"description":"","images":false},"_links":{"self":[{"href":"x"}],"collection":[{"href":"x"}],
"about":[{"href":"x"}],"wp:attachment":[{"href":"x"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"x","templated":true}]}},
{"id":205,"date":"2018-08-04T11:25:35","date_gmt":"2018-08-04T10:25:35","guid":{"rendered":"x"},
"modified":"2018-08-04T14:22:12","modified_gmt":"2018-08-04T13:22:12","slug":"citybox-oslo","status":"publish",
"type":"hotel","link":"x","title":{"rendered":"Citybox Oslo"},"template":"",
"acf":{"stad":{"value":"oslo","label":"oslo"},"description":"","images":false},
"_links":{"self":[{"href":"x"}],"collection":[{"x"}],"about":[{"href":"x"}],"wp:attachment":[{"href":"x"}],
"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"x","templated":true}]}}]
```

(I replaced all urls with "x" for brevity)

Among all other properties, there are ACF properties, like this:

```
"acf":{"stad":{"value":"barcelona","label":"barcelona"}
```

None of these queries work:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/hotels?acf={stad:{value:%27barcelona%27}}

/wp-json/wp/v2/hotels?acf.stad.value=barcelona
```

How do I build a correct URL query?

If that isn't possible, what would be an alternate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is not directly possible to make API request filtered by post meta. Because in the end, "filtering by ACF values" (on a post at least), equals "filtering by post meta".

To do this, you'll need to create your own REST handler for your own queries. A quick Google search about "adding new routes to Wordpress API" will provide a lot of examples, as [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271877/how-to-do-a-meta-query-using-rest-api-in-wordpress-4-7).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin + ACF-TO-REST-API plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/

https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api